# Let $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of events.If $P(A_k)$ does not converge to $0$ then $\exists$ an event belonging to an infinity of $A_k$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

#### Question:

Let $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of events. Prove that if $P(A_k)$ does not converge to $0$ then $\exists$ an event belonging to an infinity of $A_k$

#### My answer:

1-Let writte $A'_1=A_1 \cup A_2 ..., A'_2=A_2 \cup A_3,..., A'_n=A'_n \cup A_{n+1} \cup ...$
Now we ca note that $A'_1 \cap A'_2 \cap ... \cap A'_n=A_n$.
More over $A_n \subseteq  A'_n= A_n \cup A_{n+1} \cup ... = \bigcup_{k \geq n}^{}A_n$

2-Hence $lim_{n \to \infty } A'_1 \cap A'_2 \cap ... \cap A'_n = lim_{n \to \infty } A'_n$. So: $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A'_n)= \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \to \infty} A'_n) \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A'_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}( A'_n)$ (the limit goes out by the continuity of the probability measure).

3- By (1-) we have, $A_n \subseteq  A'_n \Rightarrow 0 < \mathbb{P}(A_n) \leq \mathbb{P}(A'_n)$ now we apply limit and we get $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}( \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A'_n) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}( A_n)>0$, so we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A'_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} \bigcup_{k\geq n}^{} A_k$ has a measure greater than zero and so as it is composed of an intersection of a countable infinity of union of events of $A_n$ this is event is too an event belonging to an infinity of $A_k$

Q.E.D.

I have two questions.
a) Is my part of the answer 3- correct?
b) Is it necessary to underline the countability of the intersection of union of events of $A_n$ in order to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} \bigcup_{k\geq n}^{} A_k$  is nesecarlly an event of $\Omega$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean an outcome, i.e. a member of the sample space, not an event, belonging to infinitely many $A_k$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thk for your help. You are maybe right english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: @RobertIsrael is my answer correct please?

Comment: Your first mistake appears to be the claim that  $A'_1 \cap A'_2 \cap \ldots A'_n = A_n$. If I understand correctly, you're defining $A'_n = \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k$, and then
 $A'_1 \cap A'_2 \cap \ldots A'_n$ should be $A'_n$, not $A_n$.

Comment: Robert points out some unusual parts of your proof. I think you are defining $A_k' = \cup_{n\geq k} A_n$.  In general it is correct that $$A_n'\searrow \cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k' =  \{A_n\quad i.o.\} $$ from which you can use continuity of probability. So if you can show $P[A_n']$ does not converge to zero then you will be done. Indeed countability is essential for the fact that $A_n'$ is an event and $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k'$ is an event.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I ve edited my prove. Indeed there was a typo error. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael  I ve edited my prove. Indeed there was a typo error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as undersigned by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel there was a typo error.

Now I ve edited my first message and I think that my answer is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[A_n]$ may not exist, we may have $P[A_{2k}]=0$ and $P[A_{2k+1}]=0.1$ for all $k$. You could use $\limsup$ if you know it. Nevertheless it is true that $P[A_n]\leq P[A_n']$ for all $n$. Also I think you mean $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k\geq n} A_k$, and yes countability is important to know it is an event.

Comment: @Michael Thank a lot for your comment.